# Implementing std::format - Part 3

Tags: c++, c++20

This is a follow-up to [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/269526/implementing-stdformat-part-2) question.

Here I’m trying to do something useful with the format specifier. I guess I should have started with `width` and `precision` but foolishly decided to first try my hand at binary formatting. So here we go…

```
#include <bitset>
#include <charconv>
#include <exception>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <string_view>

namespace jdt
{
    template<typename T>
    void toBinary(std::ostream& oss, const T& x)
    {
        oss << std::bitset<sizeof(T) * 8>(x);
    }

    void toBinary(std::ostream& oss, const double& x)
    {
        union 
        {
            double a;
            unsigned long long b;
        } data;
        data.a = x;
        toBinary(oss, data.b);
    }

    void toBinary(std::ostream& oss, const float& x)
    {
        union
        {
            float a;
            unsigned int b;
        } data;
        data.a = x;
        toBinary(oss, data.b);
    }

    void toBinary(std::ostream& oss, const std::string& x)
    {
        for (auto c : x)
            toBinary(oss, c);
    }

    void toBinary(std::ostream& oss, const char* x)
    {
        for (; *x; x++)
            toBinary(oss, *x);
    }

    template<typename T>
    void format_helper(std::ostream& oss, std::string_view fmt, const T& value)
    {
        if (fmt.find('b') != std::string::npos)
        {
            toBinary(oss, value);
        }
        else
        {
            oss << value;
        }
    }

    template<typename... Targs>
    static bool format_one(std::ostream& oss, size_t i, std::string_view fmt, const Targs&... args) {
        auto visitor = [&](const auto& arg) {
            if (!i--) {
                format_helper(oss, fmt, arg);
                return true;
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        };
        return (visitor(args) || ...);
    }

    template<typename... Targs>
    std::string format(std::string_view str, const Targs&... args)
    {
        std::ostringstream oss;
        std::size_t offset = 0;
        std::size_t index = str.find('{');
        std::size_t argumentCounter = 0;
        while (index != std::string::npos)
        {
            // check for literal open-braces character
            if (str[index + 1] == '{')
            {
                oss.write(str.data() + offset, index - offset + 1);
                offset = index + 2;
            }
            else
            {
                // check if the next part is an argument index
                std::size_t argindex = argumentCounter++;
                std::size_t startOfArg = index;
                auto ret = std::from_chars(str.data() + index + 1, str.data() + str.size(), argindex);
                index = ret.ptr - str.data();
                // find closing brace
                bool braceError = false;
                std::size_t closeBrace = str.find('}', index);
                if (closeBrace == std::string::npos)
                    throw std::runtime_error(format("error in string: {0}, column: {1}: '{{': no matching token found ", std::string(str), startOfArg).c_str());
                // check for format specifier
                if (str[index] == ':')
                    index++;
                oss.write(str.data() + offset, startOfArg - offset);
                if (!format_one(oss, argindex, str.substr(index, closeBrace - index), args...))
                    throw std::runtime_error(format("error in string: {0}, column: {1}: invalid argument index: {2}", std::string(str), startOfArg, argindex).c_str());
                if (argindex < 0)
                    std::cout << argindex << "\n";
                offset = closeBrace + 1;
            }
            index = str.find('{', offset);
        }
        if (offset < str.size())
            oss << str.substr(offset);
        return oss.str();
    }
}

int main()
{
    int a = 5;
    double b = 3.14;
    std::string c("hello");
    char d = 'Z';
    short e = 16634;
    float f = 123.456f;

    // simple arguments
    std::cout << jdt::format("a = {}, b = {}, c = {}\n", a, b, c);

    // arguments with indexes
    std::cout << jdt::format("a = {2}, b = {1}, c = {0}\n", a, b, c);

    // literal open-braces character
    std::cout << jdt::format("let object = {{\"a\": {0}, \"b\": {1}, \"c\": \"{2}\"};\n", a, b, c);

    // binary formats
    std::cout << jdt::format("char: {0} = {0:b}\n", d);
    std::cout << jdt::format("short: {0} = {0:b}\n", e);
    std::cout << jdt::format("int: {0} = {0:b}\n", a);
    std::cout << jdt::format("double: {0} = {0:b}\n", b);
    std::cout << jdt::format("float: {0} = {0:b}\n", f);
    std::cout << jdt::format("std::string: {0} = {0:b}\n",  c);
    std::cout << jdt::format("char*: {0} = {0:b}\n", "ABCDEFG");

    // too few arguments
    std::cout << jdt::format("a = {0}, b = {1}, c = {2}\n", a, b);
    // invalid argument indexes
    std::cout << jdt::format("a = {0}, b = {10}, c = {2}\n", a, b, c);
    // too many arguments
    std::cout << jdt::format("a = {2}, b = {1}, c = {0}\n", a, b, c, 3, 4, 5);
    // missing closing brace }
    std::cout << jdt::format("a = {2}, b = {1}, c = {0\n", a, b, c);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This test is always false, because `argindex` is unsigned

> ```
>                 if (argindex < 0)
> ```

---

This variable is never used:

> ```
>                bool braceError = false;
> ```

---

There is a non-portable assumption here:

> ```
>     oss << std::bitset<sizeof(T) * 8>(x);
> ```

You probably meant `CHAR_BIT` rather than `8`:

> ```
>     oss << std::bitset<sizeof x * CHAR_BIT>(x);
> ```

---

Type-punning using a union is Undefined; also we cannot predict whether `long long` and `double` are the same size.

I think it's safe to use `reinterpret_cast` instead, like this (I'm using `<concepts>` so as not to need separate versions for `float`, `double` and `long double`):

```
void toBinary(std::ostream& oss, std::floating_point auto const x)
{
    auto& a = reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char(&)[sizeof x]>(x);
    for (auto c: a) {
        toBinary(oss, c);
    }
}
```

We might choose to use `std::bit_cast` from C++20:

```
void toBinary(std::ostream& oss, std::floating_point auto const x)
{
    using array = std::array<unsigned char,sizeof x>;
    for (auto c: std::bit_cast<array>(x)) {
        toBinary(oss, c);
    }
}
```

On little-endian hardware, we'll want to reverse the byte order using `(auto c: std::views::reverse(a))` - I'll let you find out how to determine which order we should use.

---

Finally, please give some serious consideration to using a proper unit-test framework to give more robust testing than visual inspection.

Comment: I pointed out that `reinterpret_cast` _is_ safe, if you use it to view the object as an array of bytes.  It works with `char`, `unsigned char`, and `std::byte`.  But `bit_cast` is better for a simple primitive type.  You probably should not pass the floating_point value by reference, unless you are accepting extended-precision float class types as well.  As written, I'd use that function for any POD type (if you don't mind me using an out-of-date term for that; exactly how to constrain it is subject to discussion)

Answer (score 1):

You only need a `string_view` overload to take care of `string`, `const char*`, and `string_view` arguments.

```
data.a = x;
toBinary(oss, data.b);
```

That's **undefined behavior**.

You ought to have a template that handles any POD type or however you decide to restrict it, that outputs the binary representation of the object's bytes.  That would take care of the `float` and `double` cases you have now.  Be sure to use only approved kosher methods of getting a pointer to the underlying bytes, not a 1980's trick.  See [CppReference under `reinterpret_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast) where it's mentioned in a couple different places.

Both cases you show here should use `bit_cast` which is for this express purpose (as of C++20).

For a general object of some arbitrary size, you can use `reinterpret_cast` to inspect it as an array of bytes.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable insights! I'm not sure if I'm implementing this wrong, but the `string_view` overload does not seem to handle `std::string` and `const char*`: [TIO](https://tio.run/##jY/PTsMwDIfveQprSChlGwdOqA2VNl6hdxTStFhqkypxywbi1Snpsj@VxmE@frZ/n626bq0aaepxvEOjmr7UIN6RvKacXYj6kE5ZM8wZWk9Oy3bO/D@IHJr6mrwNqD9zxhjptmskaUH7ThvZaihyNlgsgewWjXR77qlM06PuHqz3KwjXeIICdgn7ZhAqUBACDqPxAeHxS9uKFwk8wHPOd0nGftit0YfG7NQA3MlVWQdc9mRBQRobcKxzcIyKSjQErUTDTwFna0iP7kmdseuExWb7ukiyy5ayPU2Phu5jWOWTYRx/VdXI2o/rMPOilssn@Qc)

Comment: @upkajdt then there's something wrong, because we normally pass both `std::string` objects and literal lexical strings `"like this"` to functions declared to take `std::string_view`.

Comment: This seems to work, but it is ugly [TIO](https://tio.run/##nZHNToQwFIX3fYobTGbKjOPClQEkcfx5ApYmppaCTaAl7QVnNL66WGB@iMzCsctzzz3facurasULpvK2vZCKF3UqIHqVaAXG5KjwN2a4Vs1Yk9qiEawca/aEhEaqfKq8NFK8x4SgKKuCoYhwWwnFSgFJTBotU0C9loqZLbWYBsGONgNt7SW4MhYhgY1PPgm441SIIuitQ//Iyg@hM5r4sICbmG78kHyRv0b3g1FTJ5g9K9MGKKtRA4dgGMDuHIKHqLOQ3SMvxpxJHv3dyqed/b8Xm50J69w9SiqEkklF98sHmvMOzA4Zkmmqd7e@9/xw/GfzZzU/ZR3xqffw@OT5u71@wHWN3bazXjkT7Zq17TfPCpbbduU8t3y5vGY/)

Comment: @upkajdt https://godbolt.org/z/Yj8rTWhfr  You should not have to declare the other two overloads at all.  I think your problem is that you are defining them to call the `string_view` version, rather than just defining the `string_view` form **only**.

Comment: This works until you have the generic function template: https://godbolt.org/z/95K35dWvq.

Comment: Something like this might work, but now I'm messing with stuff that is way beyond my skill level =) https://godbolt.org/z/T1nPKPf9z

Comment: @upkajdt forget `enable_if` if you have a current compiler.  Use `requires` which is a direct language feature for doing this, and much easier to use.  Instead of the template constrained to anything that's not `std::string`, it should be anything that's trivially copyable.  That still leaves `char*` and variations that you want funneled to be handled as a string... A "better" template match is a function that specifically takes pointers.  So `foo (T*)` will match with `T` as `char` or `const char` as well as `unsigned char` etc.  This pointer form can use `constexpr if` in the body...

Comment: ... to decide if it's a stringline thing or some other pointer where you just print the pointer's address.   Messing with stuff beyond your skill level is how you grow.  "messing around" sure beats being beyond your skill level in assigned work with deadlines and customers!